# Animating a view when an other View depends on the Animated one

Tags: android, animation

One of the things in android I understand the less, are animations.

It's kinda simple to animate a View, if it's standalone, however, if this animation is for example aligned to the bottom, and an other view is `above` this view, if you animate the bottom aligned view (move it around the screen), the view which is set to be `above` never follows this View.

**So, is there any way to make "related" views move following the animated view?**

Thanks.

If you do need a sample code, I can provide, but I think there's no need to understand.

**Sample:**

```
<RelativeLayout ......>
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewToBeAnimated"/>
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/viewToBeAnimated"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" 
        android:alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now we animate the "view to be animated" to move 25%, for instance to the top. You can see it moving but the topView stand still.

Comment: animation change only the graphical rendering of the view, not it's properties, such as those on which relative positioning rely on. You need to put both your views in a viewgroup (any kind of *Layout) and animate this viewgroup.

Comment: Both views are on a RelativeLayout. Let me add a sample code.

Comment: then animate your relative layout.

Comment: Added a layout sample.

Comment: like i said, animate the relativelayout instead. both view will be animated.